# Spring core exercices

Tags: self-learning, resource-request, java, exercises

I'm actually studying (free studying using online books) to pass the Pivotal Spring core certification and i need some exercices (online or pdf) to practice in order to master the framework as well, especially 
Spring dependancy module

Any resources would be awesome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Mouley, welcome to [cseducators.se]. I have a feeling that this is a bit out of our scope -- we generally take questions about how to teach CS rather than questions about being a student. However I'm happy to wait before I recommend closing this question to see how the rest of our community feels about it.

Comment: @thesecretmaster Since the question regards how to learn, I think it's okay as [tag:self-learning] and [tag:resource-request].